# Simulate Cree XLamp XB-D LED LTspice

Tags: led, ltspice

I want to simulate a [a white power LED from Cree](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/ds-XBD.pdf) in LTSpice. I searched for a LTSpice model and [Cree provided one](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/XLamp-XBD-Spice.txt).

By simply putting in this model in LTSpice I get this characteristic.

[image: Cree LTSpice]

I do not understand what I am doing wrong and why I don't get the characteristic from the datasheet like this

[image: transfer characteristic]

Comment: It looks like you are putting a 0 OHM  VOLTAGE RAMP in to an LED and simulating TerraAmps in time as it gets hotter.  (which is not realistic)  try a current ramp or add series Resistor and measure V vs I, and not TA vs Time

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I tried a series resistance before, but I don't get the current output I want. I tried a transfer characteristic I vs. V and if I try to pick a series resistance, so that the current output ranges between 100mA and 1000mA, the transfer characteristic is more flatter than in the datasheet

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 LTspice [D](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/D_Diode.htm)  does not model self-heating natively (how could it? - there are no thermal parameters in the model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the labels backwards so the model isn't being loaded. Should be:

[image]

Comment: This is embarrassing, thanks

Comment: @Maxim Took me a good 5 minutes of fumbling with your circuit to realize it, so don't feel too bad.

Comment: Oh, no way!  I don't think I ever would have caught this.  5 minutes is an olympic world record.  Took me 5 minutes even with the answer in front of me to see it.

Comment: Good catch! Especially since the label placement is arbitrary (you can drag the labels into the opposite positions and it will look the same either way).

Answer (score 2):

Offhand I'm not sure what you are doing wrong, but when I  use that model I get good results:

[image]

Axis adjusted to be similar to datasheet graph:

[image]